# How does SagePay work with PayPal Express Checkout?

Tags: php, paypal, opayo, omnipay

A client would like to integrate PayPal Express Checkout with SagePay. My understanding is that this is possible but I haven't been able to find any documentation online anywhere. I believe PayPal Express works by directing the user to PayPal to login, then retrieving user details from PayPal, and then confirming the order on site. However, when added with SagePay, does this work the same way, only then confirmation happens on SagePay? Can I just redirect to SagePay normally and it will register that someone has logged in using PayPal Express and automatically process the payment, bypassing the card selection screen?

I am writing in PHP and am intending to use Omnipay to handle this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting SagePay about this, it would appear that their integration of what they call 'Express Checkout' doesn't actually include the ability to take addresses from the PayPal account, they still need to come from your site

Comment: The "Express" checkout implementation leaves the user to enter details on the PayPal site, which can be collected by your site in the callback. Alternatively, the "Mark" implementation allows you to pre-register the PayPal checkout with address details from your site, which the user cannot override when they get to the PayPal CC forms. I don't believe there is a hybrid of these two approaches (i.e. pre-registering an address from your site with the ability to modify it later).

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a limitation of SagePay. If you wish to collect the customer shipping address via PayPal, you should look into using Omnipay's `PayPal_Express` gateway directly.